# How to clear value select input and out of anothor loops in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
**I have database here**
-----------------------------
| year | month | day | name |
-----------------------------
| 2017 | JAN   |  1  | John |
| 2017 | JAN   |  3  | Max  |
| 2017 | FEB   |  4  | Alex |
-----------------------------
```

and in select.jade I have three select input :

```
| select year |    |select month|   |select day|
```

if I selected year

```
| 2017 |  |select month| | select day|
```

I get result :

```
------------------------------
| year | month | day | name  |
------------------------------
| 2017 | JAN  |  1   | John  |
| 2017 | JAN  |  3   | Max   |
| 2017 | FEB  |  4   | Alex  |
------------------------------
```

if I selected year , month

```
| 2017 | |JAN | | select day |
```

I get result :

```
------------------------------
| year | month | day | name  |
------------------------------
| 2017 | JAN  |  1   | John  |
| 2017 | JAN  |  3   | Max   |
------------------------------
```

if I selected year , month , day :

```
| 2017 | |JAN | | 1 |
```

I get result :

```
------------------------------
| year | month | day | name  |
------------------------------
| 2017 | JAN  |  1   | John  |
------------------------------
```

if I change selected month form JAN to FEB :

```
| 2017 | | FEB | | 1 |
```

Which is not in database and I want to clear value in selected day as :

```
| 2017 |  | FEB |  | select day |
```

and get result :

```
-----------------------------
| year | month | day | name |
-----------------------------
| 2017 | FEB   |  4  | Alex |
-----------------------------
```

How to do this out of loops condition.

code here :

```
db.select_years(function(err, selectYears) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  db.select_months(req.body.inputyear, function(err, selectMonths) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        for (var i = 0; i < selectMonths.length; i++) {
          selectMonths[i].monthName = moment({
            month: Number(selectMonths[i].month) - 1
          }).format("MMMM");
        }
        db.select_days(req.body.inputyear, req.body.inputmonth, function(err, selectDays) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          db.getresult(req.body.inputyear, req.body.inputmonth, req.body.inputday, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            var count = 0;
            if (result.length == 0) { 
              // here if Which is not in database
            } else {
              for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if (Number(result[i].sum) > 0) {
                  count += Number(result[i].sum);
                }
                result[i].sum = numeral(result[i].sum).format('0,0');
              }
            }
            count = numeral(count).format('0,0');
            res.render("selectvalue", {
              result: result,
              selectYears: selectYears,
              selectMonths: selectMonths,
              selectordays: selectordays,
              count: count
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your code here?

Comment: @Vladimir830 now, I add code and this code is when I selected year month day